# Hook into User Save from a separate module

Tags: yii, yii2

I'd like to use modules to separate code in a large monolithic Yii app. Let's say there is a `core` module which has a `User` model, and I'm creating a new `audit` module which tracks user updates.

The audit module has an `AuditLog` model which stores information about changes to the `User` model.

If I wasn't trying to keep the audit context separate, I could just add the audit logic to `User->afterSave()`.

What is the most idiomatic way in Yii to react to a user being saved, without adding Audit specific logic to the User model?

Comment: You can run the `audit`  by [event trigger](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-events) and keep the logic  separated.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I would like to avoid any dependency of the core module on the audit module. The other way around is fine. With respect to this goal, I am not seeing how I would wire it up so the trigger in the User/core model doesn't have to know about the handlers in the audit module.

Comment: Another way is to create behavior for audit log and custom implementation as per your need. If you don't want to log user model change then simply don't plug the audit module in User class. hard to guess your requirement without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by **Insane Skull** in comments, you should use events to handle audit tasks when user is changed.

There already exist `yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_INSERT` and `yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE` events that are triggered when any object that inherits from `yii\db\ActiveRecord` is saved.

You can create handler for this events in your audit module, for example like this:

```php
namespace app\modules\audit\components;

class UserChangeHandler extends \yii\base\Component
{
    public function handleInsert(\yii\db\AfterSaveEvent $event)
    {
        // ... your audit logic when new user is created ...
        // original User model is available in $event->sender
    }

    public function handleUpdate(\yii\db\AfterSaveEvent $event)
    {
         // ... your audit logic when user is updated ...
    }
}
```

Then you can bind the events in audit module bootstrap like this:

```
namespace app\modules\audit;

use app\modules\audit\components\UserChangeHandler;
use app\models\User;
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\db\BaseActiveRecord;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module implements \yii\base\BootstrapInterface
{
    private UserChangeHandler $handler;

    public function __construct($id, $parent, UserChangeHandler $handler, $config = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($id, $parent, $config);
        $this->handler = $handler;
    }

    public function bootstrap($app)
    {
        Event::on(
            User::class,
            BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_INSERT,
            [$this->handler, 'handleInsert']
        );
        Event::on(
           User::class,
           BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE,
           [$this->handler, 'handleUpdate']
        );
    }

    // ... other definitions in module class ...
}
```

Then in your application config you add your audit module and tell the app that it should bootstrap it like this:

```php
return [
    'bootstrap' => [
        //... other bootstraped components/modules ...
        'audit',
    ],
    'modules' => [
        // ... other modules ...
        'audit' => \app\modules\audit\Module::class,
    ],
    // ... other configurations ...
];
```

This way every time the after insert, or after update events are invoked in user model, your handler will be executed. Your core application is independent on audit plugin, it's only referenced in application configuration.

NOTE: The EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE and EVENT_AFTER_INSERT are only triggered when `save()`, `update()` or `insert()` methods are used. If the user record is edited by using static `updateAll()` method or in another way that doesn't trigger afterSave() callback those events won't be triggered. If you are updating users using these methods too you might want to add your own event and trigger it when the change happen.

Comment: Ah, it's wired up in the bootstrap of the module class! Wasn't aware I could listen to the existing events as well. I am so relieved I can keep this code decoupled. Thank you!